# Уменьшение времени выполнения параллельных http запросов

Tags: java, многопоточность, http

имеется задача максимально уменьшить время на http запрос в Java. В проекте пользуюсь библиотекой Unirest, однако подобная ситуация происходит и с библиотеками async-http-client и okhttp

В чем суть:
Первый post запрос к серверу занимает около секунды, но все последующие запросы в главном потоке завершаются уже за 200мс, что я считаю неплохим результатом.
Но вот добиться такой же скорости при одновременной отправке нескольких запросов мне не удалось. Если воспользоваться функционалом библиотеки Unirest для асинхронных запросов, то на каждый из запросов будет уходить ~700мс, что значительно медленнее, чем необходимые 200.

Второй вариант, который я попробовал - это делать запросы к серверу в разных Thread'ах. Сначала я по-прежнему выполняю первый долгий запрос в главном потоке, и дальше разношу свои запросы по тредам, в одном из которых получаю 200мс на запрос, но вот в другом уже более 700мс.

Вопрос: есть ли способ выполнять параллельные запросы без потери в скорости самого запроса?

Comment: А вы пробовали выяснить на что уходит время?

Comment: Возможно что-то сервер делает такое. Еще возможно нужно после каждого запроса чистить память.

Comment: Так если дело в том, что сервер долго обрабатывает ваши запросы, то это вопросы к серверу

Comment: @RomanDanilov при тестировании последовательными запросами сервер отвечает за 200мс. Если интересно, то это сервер алиэкспресса, не думаю, что там есть какие-то проблемы с производительностью на их стороне. Задача отправить два запроса сразу, и чтобы они тоже заняли 200мс, но так пока не получается

Comment: Подозреваю, что первые 500мс уходят на DNS, установку TCP-соединения и TLS. Последующие запросы пользуются готовым соединением и у них нет этих накладных расходов. Можно ли расшарить соединение между потокам в Java я не в курсе.